# Sticky position is not working for Safari

Tags: html, css

I have images that are on the left and right that are to become sticky while scrolling.

I am using `position:-webkit-sticky;` `position:sticky;` for the class `stuck`. It is working fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

I don't have any `overflow:auto` or `display:flex` that would be affecting it. I have seen other demos where position: `-webkit:sticky` works on Safari. I just can't figure out why it isn't working on my page

Here is the page, you have to scroll down to the Celebration section to see it. 
https://www.kingswaychurch.org/annual-report/

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Now, images on the left seem to stick, but the ones on the right don't... SMH.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. There was a div above it in the code that wasn't floated. On one side it was floated, which worked, and the other side it wasn't, which didn't work. I think sticky position was relaying on the closest div.

That is my best guess.